# MongoDb get last few documents and the await tailable cursor

Tags: mongodb, cursor, tail

I want to get 5 last documents from a MongoDB collection, then keep tailing it for new documents. Can this be done at all with one query, or do I really need two queries? If two queries, what's the best way to achieve this without adding extra fields?

While answer in any language is fine, here's an example *node.js* code snippet of what I try to achieve (error handling omitted, and snippet edited based on first answer to the question):

```
MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:1338/mydb", function(err, db) {
  db.collection('mycollection', function(err, col) {
    col.count({}, function(err, total) {
      col.find({}, { tailable:true, awaitdata:true, timeout:false, skip:total-5, limit:5 }, function(err, cursor) {
        cursor.each(function(err, doc) { 
          console.dir(doc); // print the document object to console
        });
      });
    });
  });
});
```

**Problem**: Above code prints *all* the documents starting from first one, and then waits for more. Options `skip` and `limit` have no effect.

**Question:** How to easily get 5 *latest* documents, then keep on tailing for more? Example in any language is fine, does not have to be *node.js*.

Answer (score 1):

(Answer edited, it's useful to know this does not work with these versions.)

If collection was not tailable, you'd need to find out how many items there is, for that use `count`, and then use `skip` option, to skip first count-5 items.

This will **NOT** work, `tailable` and `skip` do not work together (MongoDB 2.4.6, node.js 0.10.18):

```
MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:1338/mydb", function(err, db) {
  db.collection('mycollection', function(err, col) {
    col.count({ }, function(err, total) {
      col.find({ }, { tailable: true, awaitdata: true, timeout: false, skip: total - 5, limit: 5 }, function(err, cursor) {
        cursor.each(function(err, doc) { 
          console.dir(doc); 
        });
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Looks sensible, but strangely I couldn't get that to work, still printing entire collection. I'll look into it more tomorrow...

Comment: It might be that tailable cursor does not allows skipping. In that case you might use _id indexing and $gt trick, check here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-tailable-cursor/

Comment: It seems adding `tailable:true` *or* `tailable:false` will both cause `skip` to be ignored. Then just changing to `tailable:null` and `skip` works all of a sudden. In my case I can actually use a timestamp to filter, so will probably do that.  I edited your answer a bit and +1'd it (rollback or edit further if you want), but leaving question unaccepted.

Comment: It seems `tailable` also prevents `timeout: false` from working, I'm getting a timeout if data is added with longer than 10 second interval. I must be doing something wrong, it would seem very strange if tailable cursor can't have timeout either... Any ideas?